# VBA that will copy and paste last record into first blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, so my query is probably (hopefully) a straightforward one!

I have a large database of client details, and want to write a macro for the worksheet that will find the last non-blank row, copy the row, and paste the 'format' and 'validation' into the first blank row. I want the macro to automatically run all the time (so the first blank row will always have the formats etc applied the same as the row above, even when more clients are added).

So far I have written this, and when I press Run Sub it works the first time, however if I add details in the last blank row I get an error. When I try debug it highlights the row after 'Copy last row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Copy last row

        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Rows.Select
        Selection.Copy

    'Paste format and validation into next blank row

        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1).Rows.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Also, I am running the code based on column "C" because that is a required field, so will never be blank for any of the records.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to not use `Select` and `Selection`. Try `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Rows.Copy`. Same for the Paste operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) and then clear the cell contents ([Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx)) on the new row you should be left with the cell formats and data validation.

```
with Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).resize(2, 1).entirerow
    .filldown
    with .offset(1, 0)
        .clearcontents
    end with
end with
```

Comment: btw, don't forget to turn off `application.enableevents` before changing values in the worksheet. Remember to turn them back on again before you exit the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

Comment: what's the rationale behind turning off application.enableevents? just curious

Comment: If you don't and add/modify/delete a cell value in the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro, it will trigger another event and try to run on top of itself.

Comment: I see... ok thanks for the information!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to keep running automatically - ie when I add a new client's details in the next row, I want the row below to automatically become formatted like the one above?

Comment: I did not address that point because there are a myriad of problems involved that your original code did not address. You never isolated the event code to column C. You never isolated the event code to the next unused row in column C. What happens if a value is changed somewhere on the worksheet? The code you provided is incomplete. You've snipped out portions that were important. I cannot address the issue as a whole unless I can see everything without guessing.